# make a sequence in oracle database

Tags: oracle, sequence

How can I create a sequence, which has two parts one fixed characters part and another variable integer part like "**LTR00001**" and the next value in the sequence should be "**LTR00002**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. Sequences are just integers.

But you can select a formatted string from the sequence

```
SELECT 'LTR' || to_char('09999', the_sequence.nextval) FROM DUAL;
```